# transmission watch directory permission

Tags: 18.04, server, permissions, transmission

Here is my `ls -al /NAS/`

```
efirlus@Efirlus-NAS:~$ sudo ls -al /NAS/

drwxrwxr--+  10 root                root                4096 Feb 25 18:28 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root                root                4096 Feb 25 18:28 ..
drwxrwxr--+   2 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Feb 25 19:25 Downloads
drwxrwxr--+   2 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Feb 25 19:35 Torrent
drwxrwxr-x   2 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Feb 25 19:43 tempdown
```

what I want is

when I put a seed file into `/Torrent`, then transmission automatically start download using `/tempdown`, and moving it on `/Downloads` if it completed.

so I made settings like

```
    "download-dir": "/NAS/Downloads",
    "incomplete-dir": "/NAS/tempdown",
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": true,
    "peer-congestion-algorithm": "",
    "umask": 2,
    "watch-dir": "/NAS/Torrent",
    "watch-dir-enabled": true
```

but it's not worked. `journalctl -xe` is

```
Feb 25 19:44:35 Efirlus-NAS transmission-daemon[1935]: [2020-02-25 19:44:35.224] watchdir:inotify Failed to setup watchdir "/NAS/Torrent": Permission denied (13) (watchdir-inotify.c:176)
Feb 25 19:44:35 Efirlus-NAS transmission-daemon[1935]: [2020-02-25 19:44:35.224] watchdir Failed to open directory "/NAS/Torrent" (13): Permission denied (watchdir.c:354)
Feb 25 19:44:44 Efirlus-NAS transmission-daemon[1935]: [2020-02-25 19:44:44.223] watchdir Failed to open directory "/NAS/Torrent" (13): Permission denied (watchdir.c:354)
```

fun fact is, if I add a seed in `/Torrent` manually by web interface, it is started no problem. but finished file in `/tempdown` is not moved to `/Downloads`

I followed the guide https://jkpark.github.io/ubuntu1804/10-transmission

---

some more information.

```
efirlus@Efirlus-NAS:~$ sudo groups debian-transmission
    debian-transmission : debian-transmission nogroup
efirlus@Efirlus-NAS:~$ sudo groups nobody
    nobody : nogroup debian-transmission
```

Comment: What's filesystem do you have on  `/NAS`? (`mount | grep NAS`)? Not all filesystems support the `iwatch` set of calls.

Comment: @waltinator I set that ext4... all of my / are ext4... is it unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this, to very manual and annoying way.

if anyone knows better, please answer.

---

I made a system account user, that has home folder, by `useradd -r`, e-transmission

and then, I change acl of all of transmission related directory.

```
/var/lib/transmission-daemon
/etc/transmission-daemon
/home/e-transmission/.config/transmission-daemon
```

and files

```
/usr/bin/transmission-daemon
/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service
```

to `setfacl -R -m`, as same as `/NAS/torrent, downloads, tempdown`